# What do Null and true do for new SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, xml

I've seen PHP code like this, but I've not found anything that explains it:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);
```

What do null and true do? Is there a way to check to see if the requested $url failed? Please provide an PHP example of the last two options being used. Thanks!

Comment: To learn what the arguments do, the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) for the `SimpleXMLElement` constructor would be a good place to look.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `SimpleXMLElement::_construct` is

> final public SimpleXMLElement::__construct() ( string $data [, int
>   $options = 0 [, bool $data_is_url = false [, string $ns = "" [, bool
>   $is_prefix = false ]]]] )

The default value of third parameter is `false`, so if you want to set it to `true`, you will also need to provide the second parameter.

Example:

```
//  Create a SimpleXMLElement object from a URL
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement('http://example.org/document.xml', null, true);
echo $sxe->asXML();
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. Can you provide a PHP example of how NULL and TRUE are used? Thanks!

Comment: What effect does setting it to False or True do?

Comment: @Edward When you need to create the SimpleXMLElement from a url, the 3rd parameter is `$data_is_url`.

Comment: Thanks. What does the null parameter do?